# No IP adress in virtualbox, Ubuntu and metasploitable vm

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ip

I am trying to set up a lab environment with virtual box - Ubuntu, Metasploitable2 and Kali.

When I run ifconfig in Ubuntu, I get the following output:

```
eth0      
         Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:f2:0c:d4  
         inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
         inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fef2:cd4/64 Scope:Link
         UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
         RX packets:798 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:530 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
         RX bytes:748438 (748.4 KB)  TX bytes:55894 (55.8 KB)

eth1       
          Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:51:77:cd  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        
          Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12144 (12.1 KB)  TX bytes:12144 (12.1 KB)
```

I see no IP adress, other then the local adress and the subnet.
So I cannot target the vm, from the other vm's

All vm's are set up with the same network configuration (NAT, Intel Pro/1000 MT Desktop)

How do I get an IP assigned to the vm?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the Ubuntu vm, and for some reason it fixed it.